SIM7600G-H M.2 4G HAT Terminates Python Script at 'Setting SMS Mode'
I have been able to set this up to connect to the network and send and receive sms messages using screen and minicom commands such as AT+CMGS=“************”
However, when running python scripts that attempt to do the same thing, such as the waveshare demo scripts, the script terminates while trying to set the 7600 into sms mode.
Any ideas?
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0",115200)
ser.flushInput()

phone_number = '**********' #********** change it to the phone number you want to call
text_message = 'www.waveshare.com'
power_key = 6
rec_buff = ''

def send_at(command,back,timeout):
    rec_buff = ''
    ser.write((command+'\r\n').encode())
    time.sleep(timeout)
    if ser.inWaiting():
        time.sleep(0.01 )
        rec_buff = ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
    if back not in rec_buff.decode():
        print(command + ' ERROR')
        print(command + ' back:\t' + rec_buff.decode())
        return 0
    else:
        print(rec_buff.decode())
        return 1

def SendShortMessage(phone_number,text_message):
    
    print("Setting SMS mode...")
    send_at("AT+CMGF=1","OK",1)
    print("Sending Short Message")
    answer = send_at("AT+CMGS=\""+phone_number+"\"",">",2)
    if 1 == answer:
        ser.write(text_message.encode())
        ser.write(b'\x1A')
        answer = send_at('','OK',20)
        if 1 == answer:
            print('send successfully')
        else:
            print('error')
    else:
        print('error%d'%answer)

def ReceiveShortMessage():
    rec_buff = ''
    print('Setting SMS mode...')
    send_at('AT+CMGF=1','OK',1)
    send_at('AT+CPMS=\"SM\",\"SM\",\"SM\"', 'OK', 1)
    answer = send_at('AT+CMGR=1','+CMGR:',2)
    if 1 == answer:
        answer = 0
        if 'OK' in rec_buff:
            answer = 1
            print(rec_buff)
    else:
        print('error%d'%answer)
        return False
    return True

def power_on(power_key):
    print('SIM7600X is starting:')
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setup(power_key,GPIO.OUT)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    GPIO.output(power_key,GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(2)
    GPIO.output(power_key,GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(20)
    ser.flushInput()
    print('SIM7600X is ready')

def power_down(power_key):
    print('SIM7600X is loging off:')
    GPIO.output(power_key,GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(3)
    GPIO.output(power_key,GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(18)
    print('Good bye')

try:
    power_on(power_key)
    print('Sending Short Message Test:')
    SendShortMessage(phone_number,text_message)
    print('Receive Short Message Test:\n')
    print('Please send message to phone ' + phone_number)
    ReceiveShortMessage()
    power_down(power_key)
except :
    if ser != None:
        ser.close()
    GPIO.cleanup()

I have successfully connected to the 4G network, sent and received SMS messages via direct commands in minicom, such as AT+CMGS="********". When I try and do this with a python script, the script stops and terminates while trying to set the 7600 into SMS mode. I have applied 777 permissions to the file, used sudo python3 to launch the script and also turned Hardware and Software Flow control on and off.

WHERE does it terminate and what is the error?  You should show the whole traceback.
